# Use JSON field value as record key for a Kafka topic with filebeat

Tags: json, apache-kafka, elastic-stack, filebeat, elastic-beats

I have an event (JSON message) in file, that needs to be sent to Kafka over  **filebeat** .
A JSON message looks like this:

```
{"time":1582213700.001,"interval":"2s","worker":11,"application":"1.1.1.1"}
```

I would like to send this message to Kafka. The partion key should be the application field in the JSON event message. How can I provide the custom application field within the JSON message as partion key for the Kafka record?

The filebeat.yml like this:

```
…
        output.kafka:
          version: 0.10.1
          hosts: ["{KAFKA1}:9092", "{KAFKA2}:9092", "{KAFKA3}:9092"]
          topic: '%{[log_topic]}'
          codec.format:
            string: '%{[message]}'
          key: '%{[message.application]:default}'
          partition.hash:
            hash: []
            random: true # if false non-hashable events will be dropped
          required_acks: 1
          compression: none
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/6.8/config-file-format-type.html#_format_string_sprintf
According to this reference we can refer to event field values by using the format string spec.

With this configuration the default message 'default' is always reported as key. How can I configure the filebeat.yml to extract the custom application field and use this information as Kafka partion key?

Furthermore I have tried to define a filed in the input section as follows:

```
type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
  - /var/logs/*event.log
  fields:
    log_topic: "event"
    application: '%{[application]} string'
  fields_under_root: true
```

and a corresponding kafka output as:

```
output.kafka:
  version: 0.10.1
  hosts: ["{KAFKA1}:9092", "{KAFKA2}:9092", "{KAFKA3}:9092"]
  topic: '%{[log_topic]}'
  codec.format:
    string: '%{[message]}'
  key: '%{[application]:default}'

  partition.hash:
    hash: []
    random: true # if false non-hashable events will be dropped
  required_acks: 1
```

But then the kafka partion key was always: %{[application]} string

Comment: I suggest you debug JSON events without Kafka since it seems to be unrelated to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the JSON is actually parsed, I think you want

```
key: '%{[fields.application]:default}'
```

see example - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/kafka-output.html#topic-option-kafka

You may also be interested in adding host metadata - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/add-host-metadata.html

And decoding JSON - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/6.8/decode-json-fields.html

Comment: Thanks cricket_007, for your response. I have read and tried all provided the options that you have listed. 1) I have tried to use ‘format string’ to extract the application field from the logged Json message, but the key will remain always the default value. 2) I don't need additional host information for my message routing. 3) The decode_json_fields processor decodes fields containing JSON strings and replaces the strings with valid JSON objects. But nevertheless its fields are not available, and I cannot access the read event field in the key configuration field of the kafka output.

Comment: Did you try debugging with the stdout plugin to access that same field?